# What is the exact meaning of "On Commit" in ISC DHCP server configuration?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

I know there are three kinds of events we can use for scripting in ISC dhcpd -- *commit, expire* and *lease*. My problem is, I am having a little problem in understanding the "**commit**" event. I know "commit" event means when the server has made a commitment of a certain lease to a client. But it would be easier to understand this in DORA context.

That means, **when the "commit" event will trigger in ISC DHCP server? Is it when the dhcpd is ready to offer a lease to a client? or after it has leased IP to a client?**

For example, in the following configuration -

```
on commit {
    set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
    set ClientMac = binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6));
    execute("/usr/sbin/test.py", "commit", ClientIP, ClientMac);
}
```

**when exactly will the *test.py* script will execute? Before the DHCP ACK packet exits from DHCP server or after DHCP OFFER packet exits from DHCP server?**

Thanks in advance. Cheers :)

Comment: Looks like `execute_statements(on_commit)` precedes `send_packet*` in `server/dhcp*.c`. You can probably prove it works the way you want by prefixing your test command with a `sleep()` and noting the delay on sending the packet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @anx. I downloaded the dhcp-4.4.2b1, but couldn't find " _execute_statements(on_commit)_" or  " _send_packet*_" string in **server/dhcp.c** or **server/dhcpd.c** . Can you mention which c file you are referring to in the server directory?